# Description of the lattice that gcd and lcm form on a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, principal-ideal-domains, least-common-multiple

I was reviewing my notes on principal ideal domains and I found this (to me) interesting property.

> In any principal ideal domain $D$ every two elements have greatest
>   common divisor $(a,b)$ and least common multiple. Therefore as
>   internal operations over $D$ this two form a lattice.

Indeed, if I take $a \lor b = (a,b)$ as the supremum and $a \land b = [a,b]$ as the infimum it is clear that associativity and commutativity hold.

This gives some intuition on the properties that I have for these in the general context of an integral domain, for instance $a \lor 1 = 1,a \land 0 = 0$ and others.

However, I would like to know more about the properties of this lattice. To begin with I would like to know if it is distributive and complemented, since then I would have that it forms a Boolean algebra.

**Other consequences:**

I have realized also that in a principal ideal domain thanks to the Bézout's identity the traditional lattice ordered with the inclusion and with supremum and infimum given by $+,\cap$ has an interesting connection with this lattice:

$\langle a \rangle + \langle b \rangle = \langle (a,b) \rangle$

$\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle = \langle [a,b] \rangle$

$\langle a \rangle \cdot \langle b \rangle = \langle ab \rangle$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that a PID is a UFD.
This is for $a,b,c \neq 0$ (distributivity obviously holds for $a,b$ or $c=0$)
If $p$ is prime and $p^k$ divides $a$ and $b\lor c$, then it divides $b$ or it divides $c$, ans so it divides $a\land b$ or $a\land c$, therefore it divides $(a\land b)\lor (a\land c)$.

Conversely, if $p$ is prime and $p^k$ divides $(a\land b)\lor (a\land c)$, it divides (wlog) $a\land b$, so it divides $a$ and $b$, so it divides $b\lor c$, and so it divides $a\land (b\lor c)$.

Therefore $a\land (b\lor c) = (a\land b)\lor (a\land c)$

(I left a few details to you, of course)
Therefore the lattice is distributive.

However, it is not complemented and is therefore not a boolean algebra : if $a,b\neq 0$, $ab\neq 0$ and $(ab)\subset (a)\cap (b)$.

It's a complete lattice because intersections of ideals are ideals. I don't know if much more can be said without further hypotheses

Comment: do you know what is the role of the product in this lattice ? i mean gcd is the supremum, lcm the infimum but the product is a third operation that distributes over the supremum and i don't know what is its meaning in general lattice theory....

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have a lattice-theoretic meaning. $(a)(b)= (ab) = (a\lor b)$ when $a,b$ are coprime but in general, one only has $(a)(b) \subset (a)\cap (b)= (a\lor b)$. I don't know anythin about this, but I wouldn't be surprised if one could prove that the product wasn't definable in the usual lattice language